# how to create a hash table using the given classes

Tags: python, hash, linked-list, nodes

I am currently finishing up my computer science assignment and am having trouble with the last bit and am looking for some advice.

Using the following classes:

```
class CounterLinkedList:
    __n_comparisons__ = 0

    def __init__(self, head=None):
        self.head = head
        self.__n_accesses__ = 0

    def __repr__(self):
        node = self.head
        string = str(node)
        while node.next_node:
            string += " -> " + str(node.next_node)
            node = node.next_node
        string = "[" + string + "]"
        return string

class MyString:
    '''A wrapped string that counts comparisons of itself
   against strings and delegates all other operations to the
   string itself.'''
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.i)

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        '''All other behaviours use self.i'''
        return self.i.__getattr__(attr)    


class CounterNode:
    def __init__(self, word, count=1):
        self.word = MyString(word)
        self.count = count
        self.next_node = None

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.word) + ": " + str(self.count)


def _c_mul(a, b):
    """Substitute for c multiply function"""
    return ((int(a) * int(b)) & 0xFFFFFFFF)


def nice_hash(input_string):
    """Takes a string name and returns a hash for the string. This hash value
    will be os independent, unlike the default Python hash function."""
    if input_string is None:
        return 0  # empty
    value = ord(input_string[0]) << 7
    for char in input_string:
        value = _c_mul(1000003, value) ^ ord(char)
    value = value ^ len(input_string)
    if value == -1:
        value = -2
    return value


def hash_word(item, slots):
    return nice_hash(item) % slots
```

I am required to implement a hash table without using dictionaries and each time you take a word from the list of words you will check if it is in a hash table and increment its count if it is. If it is not then insert its count into the table, using chaining if there is already an object in the hash table slot. Chaining is done with a linked list.

The output of the code if I used the input:

```
slots = 3
counts, comparisons = word_counter_hash(['list', 'with', 'no', 'repeat', 'words'], slots)
for i in range(slots):
    print(str(i) + ": " + str(counts[i]))
print(comparisons)
```

Should output:

```
0: ['words': 1 -> 'no': 1 -> 'list': 1]
1: ['repeat': 1]
2: ['with': 1]
3
```

My code so far is:

```
'''test'''
from classes_2 import CounterNode, CounterLinkedList, hash_word


def word_counter_hash(words_list, slots):
    """test"""
    hash_list = [None]*slots
    num_comparisons = 0
    for new_word in words_list:
        if len(words_list) >= 0:
            n = CounterNode(new_word, 1)
            new_list = CounterLinkedList(n)
            hash_value = hash_word(new_word, slots)
            if hash_list[hash_value] == None:
                del hash_list[hash_value]
                hash_list.insert(hash_value, new_list)
            else:
                first_node = new_list.head
                first_node.next_node = CounterNode(words_list[hash_value], 1)
                first_node = (new_list)
                del hash_list[hash_value]
                hash_list.insert(hash_value, new_list)

    return hash_list, num_comparisons
```

however my output is not the same as it was above:

```
0: ['words': 1 -> 'list': 1]
1: ['repeat': 1]
2: ['with': 1]
0
```

I am looking for any advice as to what I could do to get on the right track, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This code is a bit long. Is it possible to pare it down a bit or is it all needed?

Comment: @Veedrac, unfortunately the huge Classes code is needed because it puts in the restrictions for the assignment, as well as basis on which we formulate an answer

Comment: It might be needed for the *assignment* but right now we only need to reproduce the bug. Removing things that aren't relevant to that will help.

Comment: @Veedrac sorry about that, I've tried to cut it down as much as I can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to note is:

```
nice_hash("list") % 3
#>>> 0

nice_hash("no") % 3
#>>> 0

nice_hash("words") % 3
#>>> 0
```

These will all collide on the first box. So let's try and remove all but the first box:

```
slots = 1
counts, comparisons = word_counter_hash(['a', 'b', 'c'], slots)
print(counts[0])
#>>> ['c': 1 -> 'a': 1]
```

This reproduces the problem. Good. Now we can replace `hash_word`:

```
def hash_word(item, slots):
    return 0
```

It doesn't matter that it doesn't work well; it reproduces the problem. In fact, we no longer need the function *at all*, we can just hardcode a hash value of 0.

Bringing these simplifications through, we get:

```
def word_counter_hash(words_list):
    hash_list = [None]

    for new_word in words_list:
        new_list = CounterLinkedList(CounterNode(new_word, 1))

        if hash_list[0] == None:
            del hash_list[0]
            hash_list.insert(0, new_list)

        else:
            first_node = new_list.head
            first_node.next_node = CounterNode(words_list[0], 1)
            first_node = (new_list)
            del hash_list[0]
            hash_list.insert(0, new_list)

    return hash_list

counts = word_counter_hash(['a', 'b', 'c'])
print(counts[0])
#>>> ['c': 1 -> 'a': 1]
```

Note that:

```
del hash_list[idx]
hash_list.insert(idx, X)
```

Is just a really slow way of doing

```
hash_list[idx] = X
```

so we have

```
def word_counter_hash(words_list):
    hash_list = [None]

    for new_word in words_list:
        new_list = CounterLinkedList(CounterNode(new_word, 1))

        if hash_list[0] == None:
            hash_list[0] = new_list

        else:
            first_node = new_list.head
            first_node.next_node = CounterNode(words_list[0], 1)
            first_node = (new_list)
            hash_list[0] = new_list

    return hash_list

counts = word_counter_hash(['a', 'b', 'c'])
print(counts[0])
#>>> ['c': 1 -> 'a': 1]
```

This line does nothing:

```
first_node = (new_list)
```

and since we never really use `fist_node` we can rewrite it like:

```
def word_counter_hash(words_list):
    hash_list = [None]

    for new_word in words_list:
        new_list = CounterLinkedList(CounterNode(new_word, 1))

        if hash_list[0] == None:
            hash_list[0] = new_list

        else:
            new_list.head.next_node = CounterNode(words_list[0], 1)
            hash_list[0] = new_list

    return hash_list

counts = word_counter_hash(['a', 'b', 'c'])
print(counts[0])
#>>> ['c': 1 -> 'a': 1]
```

Then we can deduplicate the `hash_list[0] = new_list` line:

```
def word_counter_hash(words_list):
    hash_list = [None]

    for new_word in words_list:
        new_list = CounterLinkedList(CounterNode(new_word, 1))

        if hash_list[0] != None:
            new_list.head.next_node = CounterNode(words_list[0], 1)

        hash_list[0] = new_list

    return hash_list

counts = word_counter_hash(['a', 'b', 'c'])
print(counts[0])
#>>> ['c': 1 -> 'a': 1]
```

So we:

- Make a new list
- If there is already a list, set the *second element* of `new_list` to `words_list[0]` (originally `words_list[hash_value]`)
- Set the new list

Now, that second one looks wrong.

So instead you should do something like:

- If the node is `None`, make a new list
- If the node is not `None`, traverse it

  - If you find something already there, increment its number
  - If you do not, add the current one as a new node to the end

Like this:

```
def word_counter_hash(words_list):
    hash_list = [None]

    for new_word in words_list:
        if hash_list[0] == None:
            hash_list[0] = CounterLinkedList(CounterNode(new_word, 1))

        else:
            node = hash_list[0].head

            while True:
                if node.word == new_word:
                    node.count += 1
                    break

                elif not node.next_node:
                    node.next_node = CounterNode(new_word, 1)
                    break

                node = node.next_node

    return hash_list

counts = word_counter_hash(['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a'])
print(counts[0])
#>>> ['a': 2 -> 'b': 1 -> 'c': 2]
```

I've tried to keep it fairly unimaginitively simple.

I leave it to you to change `hash_list[0]` to `hash_list[hash_value]`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this very detailed answer! It makes things much easier to understand